# How to create a mock class with operator[]?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I am having a class with `operator[]`, like this :

```
class Base
{
  public:
    virtual ~Base(){}
    virtual const int & operator[]( const unsigned int index ) const = 0;
};
```

How can I create a mock class using google mock framework for this method?

I tried this :

```
class MockBase : public Base
{
public:
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD1( operator[],
                      const int& ( const unsigned int )
                      );
};
```

but that produces next errors :

```
error: pasting "]" and "_" does not give a valid preprocessing token
error: pasting "]" and "_" does not give a valid preprocessing token
error: pasting "]" and "_" does not give a valid preprocessing token
error: pasting "]" and "_" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `MOCK_METHOD#` macros won't work on operators. The solution given in [this message](http://groups.google.com/group/googlemock/browse_thread/thread/3bee5c4d556db301?pli=1) says to create a regular method for mocking:

```
class Base {
 public:
 virtual ~Base () {}
 virtual bool operator==(const Base &) = 0;
};

class MockBase: public Base {
 public:
 MOCK_METHOD1(Equals, bool(const Base &));
 virtual bool operator==(const Base & rhs) { return Equals(rhs); }
};
```