# How to use gmock MOCK_METHOD for overloaded operators?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am new to googlemock (and StackOverflow). I got a problem when using `MOCK_METHODn` in googlemock and I believe this function is widely used. Here is what I did.

I have an abstract class `Foo` with virtual overloaded `operator[]`:

```
class Foo{
public:
      virtual ~Foo(){};
      virtual int operator [] (int index) = 0;
}
```

and I want to use googlemock to get a `MockFoo`:

```
class MockFoo: public Foo{
public:
      MOCK_METHOD1(operator[], int(int index));  //The compiler indicates this line is incorrect
}
```

However, this code gives me a compile error like this:

```
error: pasting "]" and "_" does not give a valid preprocessing token
  MOCK_METHOD1(operator[], GeneInterface&(int index));
```

My understanding is that compiler misunderstands the `operator[]` and doesn't take it as a method name. But what is the correct way to mock the `operator[]` by using `MOCK_METHODn`? I have read the [docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/docs) from googlemock but found nothing related to my question. Cound anyone help me with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a mock class with operator\[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492664/how-to-create-a-mock-class-with-operator)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can't. See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlemock/O-5cTVVtswE

The solution is to just create a regular old fashioned overloaded method like so:

```
class Foo {
 public:
 virtual ~Foo() {}
 virtual int operator [] (int index) = 0;
};

class MockFoo: public Foo {
 public:
 MOCK_METHOD1(BracketOp, int(int index));
 virtual int operator [] (int index) override { return BracketOp(index); }
};
```