# How to use gmock MOCK_METHOD for overloaded object reference?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, googlemock

I have the object reference overloaded to return a value, for example:

```
class MyClass : public MyClassInterface {
  public:
    virtual ~MyClass() override;
    operator const int&() const override {
        return m_value;
    }
  private:
    int m_value{};
};
```

to get the value with:

```
MyClass myclass;
int val = myclass;
```

Now I would like to mock this operator method and found [How to use gmock MOCK_METHOD for overloaded operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43796556/5014688). I verified the example as follows:

```
class Foo {
  public:
virtual ~Foo() {}
virtual int operator[](int index) = 0;
};

class MockFoo : public Foo {
  public:
MOCK_METHOD(int, BracketOp, (int index));
virtual int operator[](int index) override { return BracketOp(index); }
};
```

This compiles without error. Now I try to modify this example to fit to my needs:

```
class Bar {
  public:
virtual ~Bar() {}
virtual operator const int&() = 0;
};

class MockBar : public Bar {
  public:
MOCK_METHOD(int, RefOp, ());
virtual operator const int&() override { return RefOp(); }
};
```

But now I get a compiling error:

```
error: returning reference to temporary [-Werror=return-local-addr]
 1173 |     virtual operator const int&() override { return RefOp(); }
      |                                                     ~~~~~^~
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I make class Bar compiling like class Foo?

Comment: What is `MyClassInterface`? A [mcve] must be posted when the question is about compiler errors, because the errors can be eliminated while filling the missing parts in your code.

Comment: The question is irrelevant to the google mock. This is the basic C++. The minimal code would be `class C {
  void f();
  void b() const { f(); }
};
`

Comment: After your edit, the minimal code would be `int f(); int& g() { return f(); }`. Don't return the reference `const int&`, this is nonsense.

Comment: @273K Thanks for answering. I would use the mocking class in my Unit Tests with `EXPECT_CALL()`. What `MOCK_METHOD` should I use? An example for the production code I have given with `MyClass`. Mocking promises testing without modifying the tested code. What would you return with the mocked function instead of `const int&()` that passes the compiler without modifying the production code?

Comment: Ok, now it's more relevant to the Google Mock. Reopened.

Comment: No, it's still the basic C++. I was expecting some fine troubles with returning `const int&` by the mock function, but they were not there. Thus, the question is an obvious duplicate of many SO questions about `error: returning reference to temporary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your original code:

```
MOCK_METHOD(const int&, value, (), (const));
```

To the updated code

```
MOCK_METHOD(const int&, RefOp, ());
```